# How to resolve error "The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)." while opening .exe on different machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I have an application which is build and executed on 'A' machine. Application is c++ based made on vs 2013.
Now i want execute application's .exe on 'B' machine. The 'B' machine has also vs 2013 installed and along with .exe i am providing all the associated dll's  but when i execute .exe it throws me error as:

```
"The application was  unable to start correctly(0xc000007b).Click OK to close the application "
```

Both machines have same OS and are 64 bit. So, please help me how to resolve the error and make .exe to open on other machine.

Comment: That error typically indicates a mismatch in the architecture among the executables. For example, the exe is built for x64, but, one or more dlls (3rd party?) are built for 32 bit.  Have you checked that all executables are built targeting the **same** platform?

Comment: "Associated DLLs" probably, copying the wrong one.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, towards the end of the trace you'll see the process loading the bad DLL and falling over.